# It's possible to run virtualized Windows on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualization

I have an Ubuntu Server, without gui of course.
It's possible to run a virtualization of Windows in another shell via command line?
So I can get running both simultaneous.
Thanks

### Update

Maybe is useful for somebody. I followed [this](http://www.zebpedersen.co.uk/?p=173) tutorial and everything went fine. I'm installing windows xp on ubuntu server via rdp :D:D
Now I need to know how to limit the resources of the host machine, but that's another story

Answer (score 1):

You can run KVM, Xen or VirtualBox and therein run Windows. But this requires virtualization support in your processor.

Comment: ok, I think it should support, how to verify? And.. I need to install the gui on the server? ?cause I try apt-get install virtualbox-4.1 and prompot a lot of packet for 583MB

Comment: You can verify by looking at 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' and looking for vmx flag. The software is pretty big, just from the size I cannot tell whether it will install a GUI. In theory you do not need one and KVM and XEN for sure do not install one, for VirtualBox I am not sure right now

Comment: Yes I have the vmx flag. I'm trying to follow a tutorial for installing virtualbox without gui. But it's not very clear and I don't unserstand if I have only the command line via ssh, where I will see the windows virtualized machine:D? via ssh?

Comment: via RFB, ie just use a VNC client

Answer (score 0):

I've followed this guide. It takes advantage of Virtual Box's built-in RDP feature.

https://kipalog.com/posts/Install-Windows-as-guest-OS-on-remote-Ubuntu-Server-using-VirtualBox